# SOLR Add spellcheck to list of docs?

Tags: solr

I'm seeing a lot of tutorials that show you how to implement a 'did you mean' feature with solr whereby a search for 'ance' might return 'did you mean acne?'

Rather than simply suggesting the correct spelling can we get solr to automatically correct and search right away?  Kind of like how google sometimes returns 'Showing results for Acne instead of Ance'

How would this be implemented? Is it possible to do in a single request?

**EDIT: My current attempt in solrconfig.xml**

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <int name="rows">10</int>
   <str name="df">text</str>


    <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str> 
    <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">5</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">3</str>

    <str name="spellcheck">on</str>


 </lst>


<arr name="last-components">
    <str>spellcheck</str>
</arr>

</requestHandler>
```

The above shows my request handler for /select, I've tried to do what Arun has suggested below.  However this doesn't get the results I'm after.  When I type a misspelling like 'clrfying' I get:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 49,
    "params": {
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "text:clrifying",
      "_": "1385375095827",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  },
  "spellcheck": {
    "suggestions": [
      "clrifying",
      {
        "numFound": 1,
        "startOffset": 5,
        "endOffset": 14,
        "suggestion": [
          "clarifyin"
        ]
      },
      "collation",
      [
        "collationQuery",
        "text:clarifyin",
        "hits",
        8,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections",
        [
          "clrifying",
          "clarifyin"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, it is returning spelling corrections.  But what I want is for solr to also provide search results based on these suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is called "collation" query
You need to setup your request handler to have a following setup:

```
<str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str> 
<str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str> 
<str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">5</str>
<str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">3</str>
```

Along with

```
<str name="spellcheck">on</str>
```

You can read about it here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent

**EDIT:**

You will need to execute the collationQuery behind the scenes and then present the user with an informational message stating "Searched for *acne* instead of *ance*" based on what you got for your collation word "hits". Collation "enables" you to do this so that you can run some logic before you replace user query with suggested query and re execute it "behind the scenes". You do not want to just let solr run suggestion query all the time... even when user is right ... You need to see if the user query got a very low number of results say 2 hits and collation has very high number of results  say 200 that means there is something wrong with user query and you need make that judgment call "behind the scenes" and re-run the collation query with most results as a replacement.  Read the documentation link above.

Comment: This implementation only returns spelling corrections.  I would like to search my index using these spelling corrections and return actual results not just spelling suggestions.

Comment: Ho would you rerun the collation query "behind the scenes", is it via an API or a configuration ? can you please shed some light on that?